# Replacing pos,neg values to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

[Screenshot#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMbtH.png)

So i have to replace positive & negative numbers in column "A", from sheet "1" to sheet second[positive] and third sheet[negative].

Here is what i tried:

```
Sub Verify()
    Dim row As Long
    For row = 1 To 20
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(row,1) <> "" Then 
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(row,1) > 0 Then 
                ActiveSheet.Cells(row,2) = ActiveSheet.Cells(row,1)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Here is what that program do:
[Screenshot#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idDOj.png)
So  as we see  i am getting positive values in column "B" sheet 1.

Comment: Do you want to **move** the values or **copy** the values ??

Comment: Just filter for `<0` and `>0` (individually) and copy the (or cut) the resultant range using `SpecialCells xlVisible`

Comment: I need to copy&paste values in sheet second and third respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not currently working because you are only using `ActiveSheet`, rather than placing data on other worksheets as required. Below is some VBA code that loops column A in your original sheet, and outputs the data to column A in two different sheets as required:

```
Sub sSplitPositiveNegative()
    Dim wsOriginal As Worksheet
    Dim wsPositive As Worksheet
    Dim wsNegative As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngPositiveRow As Long
    Dim lngNegativeRow As Long
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Set wsOriginal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Original")
    Set wsPositive = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Positive")
    Set wsNegative = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Negative")
    lngLastRow = wsOriginal.Cells(wsOriginal.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lngNegativeRow = 2
    lngPositiveRow = 2
    For lngLoop1 = 1 To lngLastRow
        If wsOriginal.Cells(lngLoop1, 1).Value > 0 Then
            wsPositive.Cells(lngPositiveRow, 1) = wsOriginal.Cells(lngLoop1, 1)
            lngPositiveRow = lngPositiveRow + 1
        Else
            wsNegative.Cells(lngNegativeRow, 1) = wsOriginal.Cells(lngLoop1, 1)
            lngNegativeRow = lngNegativeRow + 1
        End If
    Next lngLoop1
    Set wsPositive = Nothing
    Set wsNegative = Nothing
    Set wsOriginal = Nothing
End Sub
```

You will need to change the names of the worksheets referenced in the code to match those in your workbook.

Regards

Comment: Thanks, when i will get reputation.value= "15" u will get +1 to reputation : )

Answer (score 0):

Made the code a little reusable for you. Feel free to change sheet names or the last_row variable. The last_pos_val and last_neg_val are used so you won't have empty rows on the second and third sheet. You didn't specify what to do with zero, so it's currently added to the negative sheet.

```
Sub Verify()
    Dim row As Long, last_row As Long, last_pos_val As Long, last_neg_val As Long
    Dim ws_source As Worksheet, ws_pos As Worksheet, ws_neg As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws_source = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws_pos = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set ws_neg = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")

    last_pos_val = 1
    last_neg_val = 1
    last_row = 20

    For row = 1 To last_row
        If ws_source.Cells(row,1) <> "" Then 
            If ws_source.Cells(row,1) > 0 Then 
                ws_pos.Cells(last_pos_val,1) = ws_source.Cells(row,1)
                last_pos_val = last_pos_val + 1
            Else
                ws_neg.Cells(last_neg_val,1) = ws_source.Cells(row,1)
                last_neg_val = last_neg_val + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have three sheets with the names as specified for the three "ws_" variables?

Answer (score 0):

### Split Positive & Negative

- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- Both subs are needed. The first sub calls the second one.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitPN()

    Const Source As String = "Sheet1"
    Const Positive As String = "Sheet2"
    Const Negative As String = "Sheet3"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 1
    Const SourceColumn As Long = 1
    Const PositiveFirstCell As String = "A1"
    Const NegativeFirstCell As String = "A1"

    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngPositive As Range
    Dim rngNegative As Range

    With ThisWorkbook
        With .Worksheets(Source)
            Set rngSource = .Columns(SourceColumn).Find(What:="*", _
              LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            If rngSource Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
            If rngSource.Row < FirstRow Then Exit Sub
            Set rngSource = .Range(.Cells(FirstRow, SourceColumn), rngSource)
        End With
        Set rngPositive = .Worksheets(Positive).Range(PositiveFirstCell)
        Set rngNegative = .Worksheets(Negative).Range(NegativeFirstCell)
    End With

    SplitPosNeg rngSource, rngPositive, rngNegative

End Sub

Sub SplitPosNeg(SourceRange As Range, PositiveFirstCell As Range, _
  NegativeFirstCell As Range)
    Dim Source, Positive, Negative
    Dim UB As Long, i As Long
    Source = SourceRange
    UB = UBound(Source)
    ReDim Positive(1 To UB, 1 To 1)
    ReDim Negative(1 To UB, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(Source)
        Select Case Source(i, 1)
            Case Is > 0: Positive(i, 1) = Source(i, 1)
            Case Is < 0: Negative(i, 1) = Source(i, 1)
        End Select
    Next
    PositiveFirstCell.Resize(UB) = Positive
    NegativeFirstCell.Resize(UB) = Negative
End Sub
```